# Bootstrap блоки ломаются

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу понять почему так происходит, все должно быть в ряд ведь вся ширина относительная - нигде нет фиксированной, но на sm (767-991px) происходит вот такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя все блоки одинаковые по сути, и ломается только в одном месте.

```css
.product{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;





  &__carousel{
    width: 100%;
  }



  &__item{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  &__block{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;


  }

  &__img{
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__img-pos{
    margin-bottom: 17px;
  }

  &__name{
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;


    a{
      color: @gray888;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover{
      color: @green;
    }
  }

  &__pricebox{
    text-align: center;
  }

  &__pricebox-pos{

  }

  &__name-pos{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  &__sale{
    color: @gray888;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  &__sale-pos{
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  &__price{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: @green;
  }

  &__price-red{
    color: @red;
  }

  &__stars{
    color: @green;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  &__button{
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  &__button-pos{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  &__cart{
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  &__sprite{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  &__link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;

  }

  &__link:hover{
    background-color: @darkgray;
    color: #fff;
  }


  &__block-pos{
  }

  &__add-block{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__add{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top:none;
  }

  &__add-pos{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0;
  }

  &__spec-first{
    top: 25px;
    left: 15px;
  }

  &__spec-second{
    top: 51px;
    left: 15px;
  }

}
```

```html
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull">
                                <div class="product__item">
                                    <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                                        <img class="product__img product__img-pos ware__img" src="image/men/striped_cotton_blazer_2.jpg" alt="">

                                        <h3 class="product__name product__name-pos"><a href="" class="">STRIPED COTTON BLAZER</a></h3>
                                        <div class="product__pricebox product__pricebox-pos">
                                            <span class="product__sale product__sale-pos">$95.00</span>
                                            <span class="product__price product__price-red">$79.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product__add product__add-pos">
                                        <div class="product__add-block">
                                            <button class="button product__button product__button-pos ware__button">
                                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart product__cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</button>
                                            <div class="product__sprite">
                                                <a href="" class="product__link">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="" class="product__link">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Вот я еще выложил весь сайт:
http://ketty.zzz.com.ua/men.html

P. S. Попробовал закоменировать этот блок, но на его "кривое" место стал другой блок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените структуру на:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padnull"></div>
</div>
....
```

Иначе не происходит очистка потока для плавающих элементов.

Comment: спасибо! Думал сделать и так, но решил сэкономить, не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том, что блок выше получается один. Из за наименования товара в 2 строки. Остальные в 1. С помощью высоты можете оставить для всех наименований запас на 2 строки. Тогда ничего ломаться не будет.

Comment: Прошу указать чем не понравился ответ если что) Возможно я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Действительно вы правы (заминусовал не я, и не могу понять почему вам его поставили). А как это можно исправить что бы без фиксированной высоты, я думал что bs все в линию ставит.

PS вообще я примерно понял как,  у меня все строки как бы в одном row, нужно отдельно наверно для каждой строки row свой поставить

Comment: Можете найти другое решени конечно, если считаете что высота для текстовых блоков – зашквар. По сути так оно и есть. Но тут либо так, либо для каждой строки юзать .row